# YouTube 3D on Nexus 7

Tags: youtube, 4.1-jelly-bean, nexus-7

How can I enable blue/red 3D for yt3d videos in the YouTube android app? I tried watching a yt3d-enabled video on my Nexus 7 but it just plays normally, with seemingly no way to enable 3D.